# How can you find the relative spherical coordinates of an object after changing the origin?

Tags: python, camera, geometry, computational-geometry, unreal-engine4

I have an algorithm question. I am currently working on a script that generates images of an object from various angles inside of Unreal engine and pairs these images with the coordinates of the object. The way it works is that I have the object at the origin, and I generate random spherical coordinates to place my camera at. I then rotate my camera to face the object and do an extra rotation so that the object can lie anywhere in my camera's FOV. I now want to consider my camera as the origin and find the spherical coordinates of the object relative to the graph.

Currently, I am trying to derive the coordinates as in the code below. I start by noting that the radial distance between the object and the camera is the same regardless of which one is the origin. Then, I use the fact that the angles between my camera and my object are determined entirely by the extra rotation at the end of my camera placement. Finally, I try to find a rotation that will orient the object the same way as in the image based on the angular coordinates of the camera (This is done because I want to encode information about points on the object besides the center. For example, I am currently using a 1 meter cube as a placeholder object, and I want to keep track of the coordinates of the corners. I chose to use rotations because I can use them to make a rotation matrix and use it to convert my coordinates). Below is the code I use to do this (the AirSim library is used here, but all you need to know is `airsim.Pose()` takes in a Euclidean position coordinate and a Quaternion rotation as arguments to position my camera).

```
PRECISION_ANGLE = 4 # Fractions of a degree used in generating random pitch, roll, and yaw values
PRECISION_METER = 100 # Fractions of a meter used in generating random distance values
RADIUS_MAX = 20 # Maximum distance from the obstacle to be expected
#TODO: Replace minimum distace with a test for detecting if the camera is inside the obstacle
RADIUS_MIN = 3 # Minimum distance from the obstacle to be expected. Set this value large enough so that the camera will not spawn inside the object

# Camera details should match settings.json
IMAGE_HEIGHT = 144
IMAGE_WIDTH = 256
FOV = 90
# TODO: Vertical FOV rounds down for generating random integers. Some pictures will not be created
VERT_FOV = FOV * IMAGE_HEIGHT // IMAGE_WIDTH

def polarToCartesian(r, theta, phi):
    return [
         r * math.sin(theta) * math.cos(phi),
         r * math.sin(theta) * math.sin(phi),
         r * math.cos(theta)]

while 1:
    # generate a random position for our camera
    r = random.randint(RADIUS_MIN * PRECISION_METER, RADIUS_MAX * PRECISION_METER) / PRECISION_METER
    phi = random.randint(0, 360 * PRECISION_ANGLE) / PRECISION_ANGLE
    theta = random.randint(0, 180 * PRECISION_ANGLE) / PRECISION_ANGLE
    # Convert polar coordinates to cartesian for AirSim
    pos = polarToCartesian(r, math.radians(theta), math.radians(phi))

    # Generate a random offset for the camera angle
    pitch = random.randint(0, VERT_FOV * PRECISION_ANGLE) / PRECISION_ANGLE - VERT_FOV / 2
    # TODO: Rotating the drone causes the obstacle to be removed from the image because the camera is not square
    #roll = random.randint(0, 360 * PRECISION_ANGLE) / PRECISION_ANGLE
    roll = 0
    yaw = random.randint(0, FOV * PRECISION_ANGLE) / PRECISION_ANGLE - FOV/2

    # Calculate coordinates of the center of the obstacle relative to the drone's new position and orientation
    obs_r = r
    obs_phi = yaw
    obs_theta = 90 - pitch
    # Convert polar coordinates to cartesian for AirSim
    obs_pos = polarToCartesian(obs_r, math.radians(obs_theta), math.radians(obs_phi))

    # Record rotational transformation on obstacle for calculating coordinates of key locations relative to the center
    obs_phi_offset = -phi
    obs_theta_offset = 270 - theta

    # Move the camera to our calculated position
    camera_pose = airsim.Pose(airsim.Vector3r(pos[0], pos[1], pos[2]), airsim.to_quaternion(math.radians(90 - theta + pitch), math.radians(roll), math.radians(phi + 180 + yaw))) #radians
```

Is this algorithm implemented correctly? What other ways could I find the coordinates of my object? Should I be doing something in Unreal Engine to get my coordinates instead of doing this algorithmically (though it needs to be fast)?

Comment: I understand little of your explanations. All I can say is that for a change of origin of spherical coordinates, anything you do is equivalent to conversion to Cartesian, change of origin then back to spherical. There is no shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

A translation of the origin by Vector3(i,j,k) is simply the translation of the original output.

```
camera_pose = airsim.Pose(airsim.Vector3r(pos[0] + i, pos[1] + j, pos[2] + k), airsim.to_quaternion(math.radians(90 - theta + pitch), math.radians(roll), math.radians(phi + 180 + yaw))) #radians
```